# Facebook Connect iPhone custom publish stream

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, publish

I just downloaded the Facebook SDK for iOS because I need to be able to publish custom streams to user's Facebook feeds. The sample app has a method called publishStream:(id)sender that appears to set up a custom description for the Publish Stream dialog,  but when my dialog comes up all I see is an empty dialog to start typing in.  The code in the sample app is this:

`SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

```
NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];

NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"a long run", @"name",
                            @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                            @"it is fun", @"description",
                            @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil];
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                               actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                               attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                               nil];


[_app.facebook dialog:@"feed"
        andParams:params
      andDelegate:self];`
```

Should this code be populating a custom stream? If so, why isn't the demo project doing that for me? If not, what steps do I need to take in order to populate the stream with custom data?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sample app is a little outdated.  Read up on Facebook's [Feed Dialog documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to see the properties you can set, and then, just do it like so:

```
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                     @"http://www.yoursitehere.com/", @"link",
                                     @"http://www.yoursitehere.com/thumbnail.jpg", @"picture",
                                     nil];


[self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Hello, I'm using this but I'm facing another problem, the post is only published on user's wall, but not in his home feed. So other friends of that user doesn't know about this. Do you face this problem or have any solution?

Comment: but here i need 2 things such as 1]when i select a image its should be  displayed in large size image in next page. 2]when i select a text in a page it should be show site link in another page could you solve my problems

Answer (score 1):

@Mahmud: Well facebook automatically generates feeds of your friends to show your home feed section; Once you post on your wall, the home screen of your friends will get your post as per the algorithm that facebook used for populating one's home feed; Might be your feed doesn't get top postion in home feed items but it will be definitely there .... after 4 5 posts;